# How can I allocate enough memory to store an entire text file in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I'm trying to store all text from a text file in a variable. This is the code that does that:

```
        FILE *logData_fp;
        logData_fp = fopen("log", "r");
        fseek(logData_fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        int logData_len = ftell(logData_fp);

        char *logData = malloc(logData_len*sizeof(char) + sizeof(char));
        fgets(logData, logData_len, logData_fp);
        logData[strlen(logData)] = '\0';

        fclose(logData_fp);

        printf("Log data length: %d\nLog data:\n%s\n", strlen(logData), logData);
```

The entire program compiles with no errors or warnings.

The text file has a few hundred characters in it, but the strlen() value is 3. It also doesn't print out correctly and just has a weird character on the end.

Where have I messed this up?

Comment: In Unix you have the syscall mmap (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) that will help you.

Comment: I'm having to write this for Windows.

Comment: In that case https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping

Answer (score 2):

You seek to the end to get the file size but don't seek back to the beginning before your read.  Add this line after the `ftell` call.

```
fseek(logData_fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

`fgets` may not read the entire file. Perhaps you want `fread` instead?

Also, the `logData[strlen(logData)] = '\0';` assignment won't do what you think it will.  `strlen` looks for a zero byte as the string terminator, which can resulting in writing past the end of the array if that byte isn't found (and if it is, you don't need to put it there).  `fgets` may put a zero byte there; `fread` won't.

Comment: `fgets` *will* 0-terminate the buffer - it may also store the newline to the buffer if there's room.

Comment: I just tried this and got rid of the string terminator attempt, nothings changed though.

Comment: @JohnBode The zero byte is not written if the no bytes are read (due to EOF) and a NULL pointer returned.